# How to align the icons from left to right?

Tags: html, css

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    list-style: none;
}

:root{
    --color-primary:#191d2b;
    --color-secondary:#27AE60;
    --COLOR-WHITE:#FFFFFF;
    --COLOR-GREY0:#f8f8f8;
    --color-grey1:#dbe1e8;
    --color-grey2:#b2becd;
    --color-grey3:#6c7983;
    --color-grey4:#454e56;
    --color-grey5:#2a2e35;
    --color-grey6:#12181d;
    --br-sm-2:14px;

}

body{
    background-color: var(--color-primary);
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.1rem;
    color: var(--COLOR-WHITE);
    transition: all.4s ease-in-out;
}

a{
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: inherit;
    font-family: inherit;
}

header{
    height: 100vh;
    color: var(--COLOR-WHITE);
    overflow: hidden;
}
section{
    min-height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    padding: 3rem 18rem;

}

.section{
    transform: translateY(-100%) scale(0);
    transition: all.4s ease-in-out;
    background-color: var(--color-primary);
}

.sec1{
    display: none;
    transform: translateY(0) scale(1);
}
.sec2{
    display: none;
    transform: translateY(0) scale(1);
}
.sec3{
    display: none;
    transform: translateY(0) scale(1);
}
.sec4{
    display: none;
    transform: translateY(0) scale(1);
}
.sec5{
    display: none;
    transform: translateY(0) scale(1);
}

//controls
.controlls{
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 10;
    top: 50%;
    right: 3%;
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>MY PORTFOLIO</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/styles.css">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.3.0/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-SzlrxWUlpfuzQ+pcUCosxcglQRNAq/DZjVsC0lE40xsADsfeQoEypE+enwcOiGjk/bSuGGKHEyjSoQ1zVisanQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:ital@0;1&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body class="main content">
    <header class="section sec1 header active">
        

    </header>
    <main>
        <section class="section sec2 about"></section>
        <section class="section sec3 portfolio"></section>
        <section class="section sec4 blogs"></section>
        <section class="section sec5 contact"></section>
    </main>

    <div class="controlls">
        <div class="control control-1 active-btn">
            <i class="fa-solid fa-house"></i>
        </div>

        <div class="control control-2 " data-id="about">
            <i class="fa-solid fa-address-card"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="control control-3 " data-id="portfolio">
            <i class="fa-solid fa-briefcase"></i>
        </div>

        <div class="control control-4 " data-id="blogs">
            <i class="fa-solid fa-newspaper"></i>
        </div>

        <div class="control control-5 " data-id="contact">
            <i class="fa-solid fa-address-book"></i>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

hello please I'm new to programming and I'm trying to move icon buttons from the left to the right, and I've done everything shown in the tutorial[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WS70Y.png).
This has been my delay for weeks and I really need a tutor to help me learn this quickly. all i have is online tutorials.....

I was expecting the icon buttons to align at the left for real this has been my delay for weeks

Comment: You need to post the relevant HTML and CSS in your answer, properly formatted if you want help.

Comment: Please post the smallest actual code you have tried that reproduces your issue and outline the challenge it presents you so we can help you fix it.  Not just a link to a picture of code (or whatever that is supposed to be...not obvious)

Comment: I created a blank snippet to get you started.  Once updated vote to reopen.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss i guess i just did that now. I really dont know how to use use stack too. Please forgive my ignorance to all this i just want to learn new skills

Comment: hi @castro checkout this link ::  https://codepen.io/Avi-Qiyan/pen/MWqLbaz

Comment: Comments in CSS go between `/*` and `*/`. There's no `//` comment-to-end-of-line in CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the world of programming! I was a little unsure exactly what you wanted but I was assuming you wanted your icons to be displayed horizontally inline rather than vertically. To do this I'd recommend modifying your `controlls` CSS class to look like this:

```
.controlls {
  z-index: 10;
  display: flex;    /* This will display them horizontally inline */
  column-gap: 2rem; /* This is a small gap between each item */
}
```

I removed the positioning code as well for now but you can always add that back later if you want it positioned a certain way. I also added a little gap of 2rem between the icons (which isn't necessary if you don't want it). The main change needed was setting the display property to `flex`, this will put them in line for you.

Feel free to check out the changes here at this codesandbox line. Hope this helped!

[image: Edit affectionate-curie-ug83p0]

You can also read up more on [CSS Display](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display) if you're curious about other options.

Since you said you're new to programming I'd also recommend reading up on [CSS Flexbox](https://www.w3schools.com/csS/css3_flexbox.asp) as it is quite useful!

Comment: i really appreciate this sir thanks very much, this was helpful, please i dont want to be abburden but is there a way i can reach out to you if i have issues with all this.... i really need help around all this. also what if i want to move all icons to the right. Thanks alot

Comment: @castro I updated the code if you want them moved to the right but you just need to add `float: right;` to those styles to get that done